# How to get returned div's offset/position in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In my code return i have:

```
return (
  <div  className="pos__container" >
  <div  className="pos__container--line" ></div>
    {timeList}
  </div>
);
```

`<div className="pos__container--line">` has `margin-left:10%;` other styles are irrelevant.

In the function under constructor I want to get its position.

To get the offset i need to get a div first.

I have tried: 
const element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this); which returns 
`findDOMNode was called on an unmounted component.`
 
Also tried using document.QuerySelector(".pos__container--line"); which returns `null`

Feel like I'm out of the options.

Any suggestions how I could do this right or any other ways to do it ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to add a **ref** to the element you are interested in:

```
return (
  <div  className="pos__container" >
  <div  className="pos__container--line" ref={el => this.containerLine = el} ></div>
    {timeList}
  </div>
);
```

Then you can access that ref *after the component was rendered*:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // it is a regular DOM node
    this.containerLine.offsetTop
    // or with jquery
    $(this.containerLine).offset()
}
```

Comment: try `console.log(this.containerLine)` at first — is it an element?

Comment: It's undefined for some reason

Comment: It is probably because it is in a render element

Comment: Have you used `componentDidMount`, not some other callback? It should be defined only after mounting

Comment: How could this be solved, I feel like I have no other choice then use it in render code: https://pastebin.com/bReEUiSd

Comment: Just skip it on the first render e.g. `if (this.containerLine) { }`, the second render with the ref correctly set up will happen in a few milliseconds later, users will not even see anything yet.

Comment: first render?  should i have another render inside the render and return from there ?

Comment: Render is called automatically anytime the `state` or `props` are changed.

Comment: So in `componentDidMount ` calculate the position/offset you are interested in and save it to state `this.setState({someProp: someValue})`. Then use `this.state.someProp` in `render`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the lifecycle method of React which is invoked when the component has mounted.

```
componentDidMount(){
  var node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(node).offset);
}
```